# automating script via GIT for windows

Tags: windows, git, script, automation

I'm running GIT  for windows 1.7.11, I have a shell script that I want to automate, I am not willing to bog down my network running the script during the day and I have no desire to come to work at 1:04 am to run the script. I know you can cronjob in Linux but it doesn't work in GIT, so how do I run my script in GIT without touching it, every day of every week, of every month at 01:04?

I would like to run everything through GIT. Google hasn't been that helpful in what I need to do. Any ideas other than running a Linux box would be super helpful.

Comment: Is this question about git or about windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend keeping a VM or box for Linux for Git (and other things). There is way more scriptability there. Take a look at gitolite for more admin stuff on git hosted internally. On windows it's an uphill battle. Git is designed to run on Linux. Use it on that platform if you can.